# How to shorten an `each do` `raise unless` simple source code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I am trying to shorten the following code:

```
custom_values.each do |custom_value|
  raise("Error!") unless AVAILABLE_CUSTOM_VALUES.include?(custom_value)
end
```

There is a way to make that? If so, how can shorten (or, maybe, improve) the code?

Comment: Why do you want to shorten it further than that? That seems very simple and very clear.

Comment: @Mitch Dempsey - At this time I am thinking that an eventual shorten code *should be* a "positive" improvement for future maintainability reasons.

Comment: *Shorter* and *more maintainable* are entirely different things and quite often they're opposites. *Shorter* and *faster* are also different things.

Comment: @user12882 short != maintainable, readable == maintainable. In this case I prefer the collection "math", but don't mistake the two.

Comment: Don't waste time with premature optimization or worrying about excessive conciseness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I have no problem with the code you wrote, but you can shorten it like this:

```
(custom_values - AVAILABLE_CUSTOM_VALUES).empty? || raise('Error!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really shorter, but maybe a little more elegant:

```
raise('Error!') unless custom_values.all? do |custom_value|                                                                                                      
  AVAILABLE_CUSTOM_VALUES.include?(custom_value)                                                                                                                 
end
```